# How to set the priors for Bayesian estimation of Multivariate Normal Distribution when the correlation matrix has small values?

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am estimating the parameters for mean and covariance in Multivariate Normal Distribution (MVN). Following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Continuous_distributions), I used MVN for the mean and Inverse-Wishart for covariance and tried Gibbs Sampling.

$$
\begin{align}
x_i &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma), \ i=1,\ldots,N
\end{align}
$$
Sampling $\mu$:
$$
\begin{align}
p(\mu | x, \Sigma, \mu_0, \Sigma_0, \nu, \Psi) &\propto p(x | \mu, \Sigma) p(\mu | \mu_0, \Sigma_0) \ \cdots\ (1)
\end{align}
$$
Sampling $\Sigma$:
$$
\begin{align}
p(\Sigma | x, \Sigma, \mu_0, \Sigma_0, \nu, \Psi) &\propto p(x | \mu, \Sigma) p(\Sigma | \nu, \Psi) \ \cdots\ (2)
\end{align}
$$

Right hand side of (1) is MVN $\times$ MVN, so I draw a new $\mu$ in the $t$ th iteration following
$$
\begin{align}
\mu^{(t)} &\sim \mathcal{N} (m, s)\\
s &= (\Sigma_{0}^{-1} + N \Sigma^{-1}_{(t)} )^{-1} \\
m &= s (\Sigma_{0}^{-1}\mu_0 + N \Sigma^{-1}_{(t)} \overline{x}) \\
\overline{x} &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i
\end{align}
$$

Right hand side of (2) is 
$$
\begin{align}
\Sigma^{(t)} &\sim InvW (N+\nu, \eta)\\
\eta &= \Psi + \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu^{(t)}) (x_i - \mu^{(t)})^T
\end{align}
$$

I implemented above in Python, but I could not recover the true values after enough number of iterations. Is this because of the priors?

JFYI, here is the Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats as sps
import numpy.random as npr
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
npr.seed(225)

# Create Data from Multivariate Normal
N = 1000 # number of data
D = 2 # dimensions
max_mean = 0.8
max_cov = 0.15

mean_vec = npr.normal(max_mean/2, 1, D)
cov_mat = npr.uniform(max_cov/2, max_cov, (D, D))
data = npr.multivariate_normal(mean_vec, cov_mat, N)


iter_num = 10000
show_num = 9500

# Initialization
# Prepare priors
## mean
mu_0 = np.repeat(0, D)
cov_0 = np.diag(np.repeat(0.5, D))

## cov
nu = D + 1
psi = np.identity(D)

mean_itr = npr.uniform(0, max_mean*2, D)
cov_itr = npr.uniform(0.01, max_cov*2, (D, D))

# Iteration
mean_chain = []
cov_chain = []
for i in range(iter_num):
    # Update mean
    cov0_inv = np.linalg.inv(cov_0)
    cov_inv = np.linalg.inv(cov_itr)
    cov_tmp = np.linalg.inv( cov0_inv  + N * cov_inv )
    mean_tmp = cov_tmp.dot( cov0_inv.dot(mu_0) + N * np.dot(cov_inv,  data.mean(axis=0)) )
    mean_itr = npr.multivariate_normal(mean_tmp, cov_tmp, 1)

    mean_chain.append(mean_itr[0])

    # Update cov
    data_demean = data - mean_itr
    scale_tmp = psi + (data_demean.transpose()).dot(data_demean).sum(axis=0)

    cov_itr = sps.invwishart.rvs(N-1, scale_tmp)

    cov_chain.append(cov_itr)

mean_chain = np.array(mean_chain)
cov_chain = np.array(cov_chain)

# Make FIgures
dim = 1
sns.distplot(mean_chain[show_num: , dim], hist=True, kde=False)
plt.plot([mean_vec[dim], mean_vec[dim]], [0, (iter_num-show_num)*0.2], linewidth=2, color='red')

index = (1,1)
sns.distplot(cov_chain[show_num:, index[0], index[1]], hist=True, kde=False)
plt.plot([cov_mat[index[0], index[1]], cov_mat[index[0], index[1]]], [0, (iter_num-show_num)*0.2], linewidth=2, color='red')
```

It seems means are fine, but it overestimates the covariance matrix when values are small (above: one of the means, below: one of the covariance, red lines are true values).

[image]
[image]

**Updated: Using Normal-Inverse-Wishart**

```
# Prepare priors
## mean
mu_0 = np.repeat(0, D)
k0 = 0.1
cov_0 = np.diag(np.repeat(0.5, D))

## cov
v0 = D + 1.5
psi = (v0 - D - 1) * np.identity(D) # I am not sure what is proper

# Initialization
mean_itr = npr.uniform(0, max_mean*2, D)
cov_itr = sps.invwishart.rvs(v0, psi)

# Iteration
mean_chain = []
cov_chain = []
for i in range(iter_num):
    # Update mean
    data_mean = data.mean(axis=0)
    mean_tmp = (k0*mu_0 + N * data_mean ) / (k0 + N)
    k = k0 + N
    mean_itr = npr.multivariate_normal(mean_tmp, cov_itr/k, 1)

    mean_chain.append(mean_itr[0])

    # Update cov
    data_demean = data - mean_itr
    scale_tmp = psi + (data_demean.transpose()).dot(data_demean) + (k0*N)/(k0+N) *
 (data_mean-mu_0).transpose().dot(data_mean-mu_0)
    v = v0 + N

    cov_itr = sps.invwishart.rvs(v, scale_tmp)

    cov_chain.append(cov_itr)

mean_chain = np.array(mean_chain)
cov_chain = np.array(cov_chain)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your issue, but there can be issues in estimating the covariance matrix when using an inverse Wishart prior when the true variances are small. See http://newprairiepress.org/agstatconference/2014/proceedings/8/

Comment: @jaradniemi Thanks. I read [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.4050.pdf), and found [a similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282380/what-is-the-correct-form-of-metropolis-hasting-step-in-scaled-inverse-wishart-pr/312910#312910). As a part of [answering the question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312910/94337), I wrote the code for estimation using scaled inverse Wishart. I found the results look better, but not for the tiny correlation.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the sampling of the $\Sigma$, I think you might have forgotten to replace the mean $\mu$ with the sampled $\mu(t)$ from your posterior distribution of the mean.

So $\eta$ should be determined as

$\eta=\Phi+\sum_n^N(x_n-\mu(t))(x_n-\mu(t))^T$

Gibbs sampling is an iterative procedure--when you sample from the posterior distribution of a single variable, you need to replace the other variables on which the sampled variable is dependent with their previously sampled value.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling 
please

Comment: Thanks for your correction! I updated the code, but I still overestimate the covariance matrix.

Comment: When you resample the mean, you also need to replace the variance with the previously sampled value. Use $\Sigma(t)$ for sampling of $\mu(t)$ too.

Comment: Also check the derivation of $\eta$ again. I am surprised that there isnt an $1/(N-1)$ term in front of the $\sum_n^N$.

Comment: Thanks again for your corrections. For the first point, I edited the question, but the code already uses updated values in each step, so probably there is another reason why IW does not work well for small correlation matrix. For the second point, I am not sure whether or not we need $1/(N-1)$. I checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#cite_note-murphy-9) and [this note](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf), and neither of them puts $1/(N-1)$ in $\eta$. Also, the results look better without $1/(N-1)$ when I test it with my code.

Comment: I think there is a fundamental mistake in your formulation. I checked the wikipedia link again. It seems that the Inverse-Wishart prior is used when the mean is known. So $\mu$ is a known parameter rather than a random variable. So you should not sample $\mu$. If you wish to treat both $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ as random variables, then the proper prior should be a Normal-Inverse-Wishart prior. The update procedure is completely different from what you have presented.

Comment: If we sample $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ one by one in each iteration, can't we treat $\Sigma$ is fixed when we sample $\mu$ and vice versa? I do understand Normal-Inverse-Wishart prior is appropriate if we want to update both $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ at the same time.

Comment: Since you are sampling both $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ at the same time, you are treating both of them as random variables. However, the inverse-Wishart prior is only a conjugate prior for the $\Sigma$ when the $\mu$ is a fixed and known parameter. If you wish to treat both mean and variance as random variables and try to obtain an analytical posterior distribution for both of them, you need to use a NORMAL-INVERSE-WISHART prior.

Comment: Thanks again. Point taken. I updated the code and results get better (still slightly overestimates).

Comment: No worries. Happy coding